# MongoDB not authorized on admin to execute command after reinstall

Tags: mongodb

I am fresh to mongodb. I created user root and to database 'admin' but I cannot connect to other database via mongoose. So, I drop that user. Now there is not user, but I cannot connect even database 'admin'. Then, I reinstall mongodb, and still, I get 'not authorized on admin to execute command'. What should I do ???

Comment: Can I check what you want to do: do you want authorisation enabled on your database server, or are you trying to run it so you don't need to authorise?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I want authorization enable on database server, but I don't really understand how it works, so I remove the root user after I created.

and now I already reinstall my mongodb and everything is new now.

Comment: I have the same problem