# Error Connecting to MongoDB: "not authorized on admin to execute command"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to connecting my app to a MongoDB database (previously on mlab which worked). I am using the string provided for connection:

```
mongodb+srv://admin:password@cluster0.stbko.mongodb.net/name?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When I run the app, I get the following error message:

```
(node:35944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: "system.indexes", documents: [[{ns admin.sessions} {key [{expires 1}]} {name expires_1} {expireAfterSeconds 0} {unique false}]], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } }
```

I've tried this with both the mlab migration and uploading a backup copy of the database with no luck. I tried changing the privileges on the user as well... I cannot track down where this error is arising from in the code either.

I have reviewed multiple posts which I am not sure they apply to me: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932613/mongodb-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580830/mongodb-not-authorized-on-admin-to-execute-command-after-reinstall)

I have connected to the database using the mongo shell however get the following error when I tried to rung `db.getUsers()`

```
2020-12-09T17:17:43.592-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: {1607552228 10}, signature: { hash: {0 [ random numbers here ]}, keyId: more numbers } }, $db: "myDatabase" } :
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the privileges on the user you are trying with? You could restart mongodb without auth to verify the user privileges and then start up again with appropriate role

Comment: I have tried it with atlasAdmin and readWriteAnyDatabase. I will try restarting mongodb. When you say restart you mean wipe the database and start from scratch?

Comment: Can you also clarify something for me on mongodb: What is the database name exacty? MongoDB seems to be organized by Organization --> Projects --> Clusters... where does database name fall into this?

Comment: You don’t have to empty the database, just on the mongo config, turn off authentication and restart

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the versions of mongo-connect and connect-mongodb-session were out of date. After I upgraded I had no problems.

Also `db.getUsers()` has to be run for a specific user. When I tried to find my admin user it worked without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about connecting without writeMajority?  use the connection string

mongodb+srv://admin:password@cluster0.stbko.mongodb.net/name

Comment: I got the same error message. It seems to be some sort of user authorization problem.